# What is QgsCoordinateTransformContext and how to set it up for distance calculation in QGIS?

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

When setting source coordinate system for QgsDistanceArea with `setSourceCrs()` you now (QGIS 3) need to specify `context` parameter. Can someone explain what is this context parameter, and how to set it up for basic distance calculation (point to point, and they are in different crs)? The [QgsDistanceArea doc](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/other/QgsDistanceArea.html#qgis.core.QgsDistanceArea.setSourceCrs) only has the basic info so far.
This parameter is non-optional, so not providing it results in an error, and none/'' parameters are not accepted..

```
    TypeError: QgsDistanceArea.setSourceCrs(): not enough arguments
```

Comment: See [this description](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateTransformContext.html#details). You can use the context from the project: `QgsProject.instance().transformContext()`

Comment: Thank you. There is no explanation there, however, what is it, and why is this 'context' suddenly a crucial parameter for distance calculation.

Comment: No time for a full answer but: QGIS became more capable in terms of transformations and users can set specific pipelines etc (see project settings & QGIS settings). The context is used to provide user-specific settings to the transformation function.